# Weird results after multiplication in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site that does the following:

**01)** Dynamically loads data into an HTML table from a JSON url (multidimensional JSON). The data is dummy just for the creation of the website.

**02)** Has two filters at the top of the page. One for the name (1st column) which is multi selective and a second one for the numbers in the 3d column.

**03)** Has a multiplication function working. So, the number in the input box multiplies to the value of the 3d column. Then the value from the input box gets extracted from the previous multiplication result. The final result appears on the column called "Profit".

The ***issue*** is that the result in this link :  [LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/TEST/) and more specifically in the first row is not the expected :

[image]

The result should be `(2*1.91) - 1.91 = 1.91`

The multiplication script is here :

```
//Multiplication of the cells function
function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var $val1 = $('.metric1', this).val();
        var $val2 = $('.metric2', this).text();
        var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1;
        $('.multTotal', this).text($total.toPrecision(3));

        var $val3 = $('.multTotal', this).text();
        var $total2 = $val3 / 100
        $('.metric3-100', this).text($total2.toPrecision(3));

        var $total3 = $val1 / 100
        $('.metric1-100', this).text($total3.toPrecision(2));

        mult += $total;
    });
}
```

but I guess it interferes with the `.js` file because it has more functions running.

Comment: jQuery is loaded multiple time and different version `  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` however this may not necessarily cause the problem.

Comment: Could you explain your variables? 2 * 0.91 is 1.82 so you might have a math error

Comment: @bhantol I removed them.

Comment: @Duck The syntax is good. I am using this function for long now and I had no issues.

Comment: Right now your equation is thus: `(2*1.91) - 2` (which equals 1.82).  You want to change minus $val1 to minus $val2

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I could not do that because the JSON data does not load if it derives from an http

Comment: ...which is why you need to read that link I gave you, paying the most attention to "Minimal", which means if the issue is with your calculation function, you shouldn't need any JSON from anywhere.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The speculation was that it was interfering with the other scripts because for the same site, that happened numerous times. In this case, I made a stupid observation. I was thinking of deleting the ticket too but I kept it.

Comment: Without the code here on the site, the question is of little use to future readers, especially if that link goes stale.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In this case the code help. I will try to load a snippet next after putting static JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging through this, I think you want to subtract `$val2` not `$val1` for your `$total`:

[image]

Line 75 should be: `var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val2;`

Comment: I got so dizzy that I can't believe that I spent time for this. That is how it should be. I only did the calculation wrong for the first row. And I repeated the same mistake for over an hour. I think I should delete the ticket.

Comment: If you think that this post and the answers don't add a lasting value to SO it is a good idea to delete - I have done it before. It is a good service to not clutter the site.